# Why are my clickCounts all adding on top of each other rather than counting separately?

Tags: javascript, html, count, counter

```
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Vote!</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 0;
function countClicks() {



x += 1
document.getElementById( "counting" ).innerHTML = x;

    ClickCount++;
    return true;
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 0;
function countClicks1() {
x += 1
document.getElementById( "counting1" ).innerHTML = x;

    ClickCount++;
    return true;
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 0;
function countClicks2() {



x += 1
document.getElementById( "counting2" ).innerHTML = x;

    ClickCount++;
    return true;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="chart1">
<ul>
<li>
<img src="../Pictures/BWS + L.A +KUSH/Game.RED_Album_Cover.jpg" alt="red album"><br>
<input type="button" value="VOTE" name="clickOnce" onclick="return countClicks();" />
<div id="counting"></div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="../Pictures/BWS + L.A +KUSH/Game.RED_Album_Cover.jpg" alt="red album"><br>
<input type="button" value="VOTE" name="clickOnce" onclick="return countClicks1();" />
<div id="counting1"></div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="../Pictures/BWS + L.A +KUSH/Game.RED_Album_Cover.jpg" alt="red album"><br>
<input type="button" value="VOTE" name="clickOnce" onclick="return countClicks2();" />
<div id="counting2"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var x` is a global variable. Once it has been declared, then your functions will use the same variable. So in both `countClicks` and `countClicks1` they are using the same variable.

Change the second to use `var x2 = 0`

Answer (score 1):

ummm...

because x is a global variable and clickCount always using the same variable...

also, I'd suggest you to DRY your code, and make the function operate based on a parameter, you DON'T need 3 functions which all do exactly the same thing.